# CakePHP Database - MyISAM, InnoDB, or Postgresql

Tags: mysql, database, performance, postgresql, innodb

I've always just used MyISAM for all of my projects, but I am looking for a seasoned opinion before I start this next one.

I'm about to start a project that will be dealing with hundreds of thousands of rows across many tables. (Several tables may even have millions of rows as the years go on). The project will primarily need fast-read access because it is a Web App, but fast-write obviously doesn't hurt. It needs to be very scalable.

The project will also be dealing with sensitive and important information, meaning it needs to be reliable. MySQL seems to be notorious for ignoring validation.

The project is going to be using CakePHP as a framework, and I'm fairly sure it supports MySQL and Postgresql equally, but if anyone can disagree with me on that please let me know.

I was tempted to go with InnoDB, but I've heard it has terrible performance. Postgresql seems to be the most reliable, but also is not as fast as MyISAM.

If I were able to upgrade the server's version of MySQL to 5.5, would InnoDB be a safer bet than Postgres? Or is MyISAM still a better fit for most needs and more scaleable than the others?

Comment: This question is not suitable here since answers would be opinion based. I will say that while MyISAM can be faster in some cases, but lack of foreign key constraints and transactions is pretty limiting.

Comment: I realize it can be subjective, but there are also facts that lead to those opinions. What do you mean by foreign key constraints?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified that question. CakePHP has associated models and creates SQL queries accordingly. Would it make a difference if the tables themselves were aware of their relations? Or could that actually hurt performance?

Comment: @LukeSapan Read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html . FK constraints prevent the creation of dangling relationships between records and should *always* be used unless you have an extremely good reason not to. If CakePHP doesn't create them as part of DDL generation, I'd be looking for another framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only answer that this really needs is "not MyISAM". Not if you care about your data. After all, `/dev/null` has truly amazing performance, but it doesn't meet your reliability requirement either ;-)

The rest is the usual MySQL vs PostgreSQL opinion that we close every time someone asks a new flavour because it really doesn't lead to much that's useful.

What's way more important than your DB choice is how you use it:

- Do you cache commonly hit data that can afford to be a little stale in something like Redis or Memcached?
- Do you avoid "n+1" selects from inefficient ORMs in favour of somewhat sane joins?
- Do you avoid selecting lots of data you don't need?
- Do you do selective cache invalidation (I use `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` for this), or just flush the whole cache when something changes?
- Do you minimize pagination and when you must paginate, do so based on last-seen ID rather than offset? `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id > ? ORDER BY id LIMIT 100` can be immensely faster than `SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY id OFFSET ? LIMIT 100`.
- Do you monitor query performance and hand-tune problem queries, create appropriate indexes, etc?

(Marked community wiki because I close-voted this question and it seems inappropriate to close-vote and answer unless it's CW).

Comment: Haha thank you. I'm still concerned that pages will take forever to load after I move away from MyISAM, but that's more a thing of the past right?

Comment: @LukeSapan Well, for highly scalable read-heavy loads you should be looking into a caching layer - memcached, redis, etc. I use PostgreSQL with triggers that send NOTIFY events to a worker that LISTENs for them and invalidates cache entries when the DB changes, but there are all sorts of approaches depending on your needs. I don't use (Cake)PHP so I don't know how well that approach would fit in there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful answer!

Comment: Also I've never done any work with caching layers but CakePHP natively supports Memcached and Redis so I will definitely look into that.